# Do outliers begin from or above the whisker-limit?

Tags: python, outliers

Does outliers begin on the whisker limit or above it?

In the (Python) example below the calculcated upper whisker limit is `64.8125`. Is a value of `64.8125` an outlier (`>= upper_limit`)? Or the outliers are higher then the limit (`> upper_limit`)?

```
>>> import seaborn as sns
>>> df = sns.load_dataset('titanic)

>>> df.age.quantile([.25, .5, .75])
0.25    20.125
0.50    28.000
0.75    38.000
Name: age, dtype: float64

>>> q1, q2, q3 = df.age.quantile([.25, .5, .75])
>>> iqr = q3 - q1
>>> whisker_length = iqr * 1.5

>>> upper_limit = q3 + whisker_length
>>> lower_limit = q1 - whisker_length
>>> lower_limit, upper_limit
(-6.6875, 64.8125)
```

Comment: related https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/603446/56940

Comment: No it don't because it doesn't fit to my MWE.

Comment: What is an "MWE" and why should it matter here?  BTW, I found the duplicate threads by searching for "boxplot fence" and "boxplot whisker outlier" and looking at the top-voted hits.  I'm sure you can find even more answers by searching further.

Comment: MWE = https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I thought it might be that, but your example is by no means "minimal."

Answer (score 2):

Under Tukey's approach, the whiskers are specifically drawn in each direction *to the furthest observation from the median that is still within (or equal to) the inner fence*. If a point is exactly on the inner fence, the whisker includes it.

A marked point must therefore be *outside* the inner fences.

That is strictly above on the high side (above the upper inner fence) but *strictly below* on the low side (below the lower inner fence).

Here's an illustration where there's points above the upper inner fence.

[image: Box plot with calculation of inner fence shows and showing points strictly outside the fences marked with circles]

Comment: Can you please fit your answer to my MWE and give a number.

Comment: No. ... That looks like I'd be doing homework. I believe my answer is unambiguous.

Comment: I'm far behind homework. I just try to "translate" it into my world. I know Tukey of course. But I don't "speak" math. Also English isn't my nativ language. So I just want to be sure if I understand it correct. My assumption is `> upper_limit` but I'm not sure without confirmation based on my MWE.